# Text field validation in JavaFX using marks

Tags: java, css, validation, user-interface, javafx

I'm using JavaFX for my application's GUI. I want to implement a validation method for all the textfields inside the sign up window. I want to check them all and than, whether they are true or false, I want to use a mark to show the user what field is incorrect. I also want to be able to show a small message box when I hover the mouse pointer over those marks.[image]

Comment: What is the actual question? What code have you written? Where are you stuck or what is not working properly?

Answer (score 1):

Simple way is to create **HBox** , put TextField,Label in there ,label will be [Bound](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm) on the textProperty/ or do it with listener

```
txtField.textProperty().addListener((v, oldValue, newValue) -> {

//code here if valid, set label visible false, else set label visible true(red image crossed  or whatever)

   });
```

, when value changes it will check if that is ACCEPTABLE/FAILED state , for instance empty box.States will be changed on property change , use array of your hboxes to check if they are valid or invalid at the time , you can check this based on visibility of Label or internal boolean state value.

For the hover over part , use [Tooltip](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Tooltip.html) on label.

If you want to go lazyer way , take a look at [controlsfx validation](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/features/#decorationvalidation) it will take care of graphics for you.And its already embedded in its component.Just create validation process

Good beginner reference might be newboston videos so you understand concept.In javafx you gonna use property binding ,listeners etc often , get familiar with them as you cant avoid it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s8GomyEOA8w

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Zi2L0kHSx4

Answer (score 0):

Since you've given no code I can't give you answer that involves actual coding, because I've got no way of knowing whether or not what I give you will be viable or conflict etc..

In regards to the validation that depends entirely on how your accessing a username/password to compare it to what the user has entered and with out knowing how you're thinking of doing it I cannot give you a good answer.

There are quite a few options to display your red x, you could draw it internally etc..

But the easiest is probably going to be creating an image and importing it to your project, you can set a label next to your JTextField and have the picture set to that lable. Once the user inputs the username/password if either or both are incorrect you could have a method that would set the label to be visible.

The message box is as simple as a tooltip that you could also place on the label which would tell the user that the information they entered is wrong.